# Create as many views as there are object in the array

Tags: ios5, uiview, xcode4.2

I would like to create a view where this subview will be in repeated for as many times as there are element in an array

Fx

```
Array *labelText = [NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Title1",@"Title2",nil];
```

2 elements in this array, so two subviews would be needed.

I will get the appropriate from the *labelText.

I don't know if it's possible, but i would be a foul not to ask the experts :)

[image: Three rows with four view in each]

Comment: Do you want the views to resize based on how many there are?  Do you want them to show up in any particular place?  Do you want the created views to be draggable?  A lot of this information is intermingled, so some specificity would be appreciated.  Tell me what you want, and I will paste you some code.

Comment: Fair fair. This is meant for the ipad, so i would like the views to stay the same size and there should be four views when i horizontal mode and six in landscape mode. Then the next three should be below the the first row, and then third row should be below the second row etc. So they views would be in a scrollview and could expand for as long as needed. The spacing between them should be the same on both sides and on top and bottom. And no, the views should not be draggable, nor editable to the user. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If you see the new picture in my original post, that might give a more clear description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very possible indeed. You might want to take a look at the excellent [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)